# Unselect after making a cut in Davinci Resolve 15

Tags: davinci-resolve

After I make a cut in the middle of the clip I would like to have only the part of the clip I want selected not both (previously only one) clips selected, since it takes more time to than deselect both and select only the one i want deleted.
Any advice?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about the exact steps you're using to get a good answer.  Is "Selection Follows Playhead" active in the "Timeline" menu, or not?  When you "make a cut in the middle of the clip," are you using the blade tool, or keyboard shortcuts?  In many cases in Resolve, toggling the SFP control will give you the behavior you want if it's not behaving the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you work in the edit window, I guess you're using following:

1. press <kbd>B</kbd> to select Blade cut tool
2. mouse click on clip where you want to cut it
3. press <kbd>A</kbd> to switch to select mode
4. select cutted part I want to delete
5. press <kbd>Delete</kbd>

You can achieve something similar with Trim tool:

1. press <kbd>T</kbd> to select Blade cut tool
2. mouse click on clip where you want to cut it
3. press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to Trim start (from left)
   or Trim End with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (from right side)

This will make the clip shorter and if you click on the clip you'll see that it continues (the white box) only some part is shown:

[image: clip trimming]

now you can move which part of the clip is shown by pressing <kbd><</kbd> or <kbd>></kbd> (comma and dot keys)

Comment: This answer doesn't mention the "Selection Follows Playhead" toggle, which fundamentally changes the way editing behaves in Resolve, nor does it mention the Auto Select target toggles, which also have a significant impact on how the edit controls behave.  If SPF is on, whatever clip's under the playhead will become re-selected if the playhead moves in the example above.  And if you'd used command-B to place the cut instead of "B" key, then click, the clip would stay selected the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I use shortcuts to make my edits (B for making a cut instantly). after I make an edit I would like only the second clip selected not both (now there are two clips bcz I split them)

[image]

Here you can see both clips being selected. How do I tell the software I would only like the second clip selected by default?

Thanks!!